# Ют і пів'ют - у чому різниця?

Tags: переклад, значення-слів, різниця-між-словами

Намагаюся перекласти poop deck з анґлійської. [Речення](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=mQN8CwAAQBAJ&pg=PA79&lpg=PA79&dq=Above%20his%20head,%20on%20the%20break%20of%20the%20poop,%20the%20night-watchman%20rang%20a%20double%20stroke.&source=bl&ots=fyH1MraK2R&sig=ACfU3U0tGo62KM9nl4fXEj_L5NEKV0i3mg&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj4jNyHgOniAhUPcZoKHWYNARAQ6AEwEnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=Above%20his%20head%2C%20on%20the%20break%20of%20the%20poop%2C%20the%20night-watchman%20rang%20a%20double%20stroke.&f=false):

> Above his head, on the break of the **poop**, the night-watchman rang a double stroke.

Це якась частина корабля. І ось у чому проблема:

1. На [вікі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D1%82) відповідник: *ют*.
2. [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/piv.jut) також дає як абсолютний синонім: *пів'ют*.

На СУМ-11 обидва слова мають таке визначення:

> Кормова частина верхньої палуби судна.

Чим вони відрізняються та чи відрізняються?

В яких джерелах можна знайти визначення?

Comment: Знахоџу словопохоџенє _ют > hut_, а ось _пів_ нїде. Згаданиı СУМ не надовитı приклади вживу. Дивненıко.

Comment: Пів'ют це надбудова або додаткова палуба над ютом. Це з рос вікі - Полуют:
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B#П

Comment: @ЮрійГладьо ви можете написати відповідь чи не хочете?

Comment: Останнє питання було: Де можна знайти визначення? І я лиш вказав джерело, я не є корабельний експерт, лиш погуглив 2 хв. (Та й давно я вже не маю бажання тут відповідати... час від часу лиш заглядаю з цікавості)

Comment: @ЮрійГладьо вікіпедію я не рахую за джерело. Мене цікавлять українські словники мариністики, які поки не можу знайти (і починаю думати, що їх не існує). Але питання основне - саме про різницю між словами, а не про джерела. Відповідей може бути дві окремих.

Comment: Шчо схоже на калıку half-poop, але нормалного словника не знаıти.

Comment: @P.Vowk є Англо-український словник морських термінів, Державний університет інфраструктури та технологій.

Comment: @P.Vowk можливо, вам буде цікаве також:

* Горбач О. Українська морська й судноплавна термінологія//Вісті братства колишніх вояків і УД УНА. – Мюнхен, 1958. – С.10, 11.     


* Горбач О. Українська морська й судноплавна термінологія / Олекса Горбач // Відбитки з журналу „Вісті Братства колишніх Вояків і УД УНА”. – Чч. 3-6 (77-80) та 11-12 (85-86). – Мюнхен, 1958. – С. 3-28.          

* Андріянова О. Я. Військово – морська термінологія української
мови: етапи формування та семантика : автореф. дис. на здобуття наук. ступеня
канд. філ. наук : спец. 10.02.01. Запоріжжя, 2011. 21 с.